Error "WebAssetManager is locked, you came late"
I'm using Joomla 4.4, and this code to load a module to display it in a plugin with onAfterRender event.
echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadmoduleid 16}');

But the website say error WebAssetManager is locked, you came late
If I use {loadmoduleid 16} in a Joomla article it still working fine. I don't sure what's wrong?
Please help.
Thanks

Which plugin event are you using? Also you should not be using the shortcodes inside plugins like that. Instead use Document Renderer and Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper to render the module.

@Sharky I'm using it in the onAfterRender event, if I use ModuleHelper, some are ok, some still say same error, strange.

You should update your question with this information.

This is happening because you're trying to render modules during onAfterRender event, which occurs after the document has already been rendered. This is conceptually wrong. At this point changes made to the document have no effect and no more assets can be added, which is why an exception is thrown. Even if there was no exception thrown, you'd still end up with broken modules because their assets would be missing. So while it's possible to solve the error by loading a new document instance, it's not really a sensible thing to do.
Depending on what you're trying to do, you could try using an earlier event like onAfterDispatch or onBeforeRender and making changes to specific parts of the document. For example, to render a module in component area:
public function onAfterDispatch()
{
    // Load module renderer and render the module.
    $content = $document->loadRenderer('module')->render(Joomla\CMS\Helper\ModuleHelper::getModuleById('16'));

    // Add module content to component area.
    $document->setBuffer($content, 'component');
}

